# combining mouseenter,mouseleave and click events in changing div background

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my current code and I've been trying to work it out for over an hour already:

```
$('#menu_list').bind('mouseenter mouseleave click', function(event){
    if(event.type == 'click') {
        $('#list_img').css('background-image', 'url(<?=base_url()?>/assets/css/images/list_active.png)');
        $('#add_img').css('background-image', 'url(<?=base_url()?>/assets/css/images/add_inactive.png)');
        $('#search_img').css('background-image', 'url(<?=base_url()?>/assets/css/images/search_inactive.png)');
        $('#list_text').css('color', 'black');
        $('#add_text').css('color', '#C0C0C0');
        $('#search_text').css('color', '#C0C0C0');
    } else if(event.type == 'mouseenter') {
        $('#list_text').css('color', 'black');
        $('#list_img').css('background-image', 'url(<?=base_url()?>/assets/css/images/list_active.png)');
    } else if(event.type == 'mouseleave') {
        $('#list_img').css('background-image', 'url(<?=base_url()?>/assets/css/images/list_inactive.png)');
    }
});
```

What it should do is when I hover, the icon changes. But when I clicked, the icon stays on as active until I clicked on another item. There is no problem with the mouseenter/mouseleave. The problem starts with the click. Upon click, it does the job, but upon moving the mouse, the mouseleave function activates. Meaning the icon becomes inactive again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var activeItem;
$('#menu_list').bind('mouseenter mouseleave click', function(event){ 
    if(event.type == 'click') { 
        $('#list_img').css('background-image', 'url(<?=base_url()?>/assets/css/images/list_active.png)'); 
        $('#add_img').css('background-image', 'url(<?=base_url()?>/assets/css/images/add_inactive.png)'); 
        $('#search_img').css('background-image', 'url(<?=base_url()?>/assets/css/images/search_inactive.png)'); 
        $('#list_text').css('color', 'black'); 
        $('#add_text').css('color', '#C0C0C0'); 
        $('#search_text').css('color', '#C0C0C0');
        activeItem = this;          
    } else if(event.type == 'mouseenter') { 
        $('#list_text').css('color', 'black'); 
        $('#list_img').css('background-image', 'url(<?=base_url()?>/assets/css/images/list_active.png)'); 
    } else if(event.type == 'mouseleave' && !list_clicked) {
        if(activeItem != this) {        
            $('#list_img').css('background-image', 'url(<?=base_url()?>/assets/css/images/list_inactive.png)'); 
        }
    } 
});
```

You just need to keep track of your active item.

Comment: Thanks. I think this is the best thing in my current situation.

Comment: @braindead Your else if branch nonsense. Just write  `else if(event.type == 'mouseleave' && activeItem != this)`

Comment: Yeah, that '&&' part there is not supposed to be there. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, why are you making this so complicated in your jQuery? Why not use a css class based system.

Have your css like this (obviously change this as you require ;)

```
.normal { color:#000; background-image: url(foo.jpg) }
.click { color:#2B2B2B; background-image: url(foo.jpg) }
.mouseIn { color:#F00; background-image: url(foo.jpg) }
.mouseOut { color:#FFF; background-image: url(foo.jpg) }
```

Then using jQuery

```
$('#menu_list').click(function() {

   $('#list_img').addClass("click");
   $('#add_text').addClass("example");
});

$('#menu_list').mouseenter(function() {

   $('#list_img').addClass("mouseIn");

});

$('#menu_list').mouseleave(function() {

   $('#list_img').addClass("mouseOut");

});
```

I persume you will also need to remove class's as well? You can use the opposite of `addClass` called `removeClass`. You would place these inside the functions shown above

Comment: Thanks. I honestly found what I did to be more convenient (personal preference). I'll try what you're suggesting, more clean and tidy.

Comment: This code won't work - you have to toggle the classes and check in the mouseleave function if the item has been clicked.

Comment: just a question, if I write my css on another file, include it using `<link>` tag, it should work out of the box? the `.addClass` functionality of jquery? e.g. I have something like 
<div class="1"><div class="2"><a id="a1"><div id="thisDiv"></div></a></div></div>
and the div that I want the css to get applied to is the one with `thisDiv` id?

Answer (score 1):

First of all I'd advise you for the sake of maintainability to separate those events and write 3 separate eventhandlers.

Second, what is `list_clicked`? The variable seems to be out of scope thus is undefined and always yields true. Check for a class on the element instead, this is easier...

Third: put all these styles into some css-classes (e.g. `active` and `clicked` in my example), this makes the whole thing pretty easy.
Something like that should work:

```
$('#menu_list').click(function() {
   /* alternate the classes by clicking - the class "clicked" is there to indicate 
     that it has been activated by click and won't be removed by mouseout*/
   $(this).toggleClass("active clicked");
});

$('#menu_list').mouseenter(function() {
   /* Just add the "active" class */
   $(this).addClass("active");
});

$('#menu_list').mouseleave(function() {
   /* If the element has not been clicked...*/
   if (!$(this).hasClass("clicked")){
      /*...remove the "active" class */
      $(this).removeClass("active");
   }
});
```

The CSS-classes would look something like this:

```css
.active #list_img{
    background-image:url(<?=base_url()?>/assets/css/images/list_active.png);
}
.active #list_text{
    color:black;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I removed list_clicked already. It's not supposed to be there.

I actually tried something like '.addClass("active")' earlier. I don't know. It does not seemed to work. I wanted to implement it as what you've suggested. It's just that, it didn't work earlier. I'll go over again if I miss something.

Comment: @braindead that's why i added a separate `clicked` class, so that you can check for the existence of this class in the mouseleave function. It should work this way.

Comment: I'm honestly a beginner and having a little difficulty with what you're suggesting, but I'll try it. I've used toggleClass earlier without succeeding. Thanks.

Comment: @braindead No problem, just take your time and try if you can work it out. Feel free to ask if you have problems. I added some additional info for you.

Answer (score 0):

Well for starters, you're checking for a variable list_clicked, which doesn't appear to be being set in your click handler - This means !list_clicked will always return true... So that might not help.